# Make absolute-positioned element scroll when cut off

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, absolute

On my website, there is an FAQ section that is positioned absolute so that it may slide in from off-screen. Go to http://www.mordstats.com and click the big "?" in the top-right and then "Frequently asked questions" to see it.

[image: Screenshot]

When the browser window height is too short and the FAQ section is cut off, it does not scroll.  Is it possible to fix this while still allowing the FAQ section to keep its position and transition effects?

Adding `overflow-y: auto` to `#faqMenu.menu` and/or setting `position: fixed` did not work.  Honestly not sure what else to try.

Full HTML code can be viewed by viewing page source on http://www.mordstats.com, and CSS styling [here](http://mordstats.com/res/style.css).  Relevant bits:

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* other stuff */
  transition: right 0.3s;
}

/* menuHide is removed via JavaScript when corresponding text is clicked */
.menu.menuHide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 124px;
  width: 275px;
  top: 71px;
  right: -275px;
  transition: right 0.4s;
}

#faqMenu.menuHide {
  right: -400px;
}

#faqMenu.menu {
  top: 195px;
  height: auto;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  /* other stuff */
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBar">
  <!-- left and center divs -->
  <div id="menuRight" class="menuBox">
    <!-- other things -->
    <div id="faqMenu" class="menu menuHide" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
      <!-- FAQs here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the FAQ section to scroll when it is cut off, but it does not.

Comment: how exactly can this issue be reproduced?

Comment: Just shrink the height of the browser window and open the FAQ section.  The issue is also present on MacOS (or at least my MacBook) due to the presence of the Dock.

Comment: I'm going to update your question and provide a screenshot.  The short answer is, yes, you should be able to accomplish this with media queries on height, when you know the height of your FAQ.

Comment: If you're still haven't problems here, let me know... though, please make sure to upvote and accept and answer in the event an answer solves your issue or addresses your question.

Comment: Sorry, I've been a little distracted and haven't had the motivation to try out your solution, I do appreciate the response though and I'll be sure to do that once I give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to resolve your scrolling issue - you really need only define `bottom:0` and `overflow-y:scroll` with the correct order of selector with highest precedence by specifity: Namely `div#faqMenu.menu`. If you define your declarations on `#faqMenu.menu` or `div#faqMenu`, you may not have had the highest precedence, some declaration may not have applied.  You can review [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) (mentioned in the top answer of a unrelated S.O. question on this topic of style selector precedence order)

[image: Screen of resolved issue in webtools]

In the above screenshot, you can see in the inspector stylesheet snippet that I designated `overflow-y` here unconditionally, but I applied a media query on `max-height` to determine when `bottom:0` should be applied. The value is set there was arbitrary, and it was really only to ensure the FAQ didn't always latch to the bottom since it wasn't really mentioned as a desire here.  In addition, I unset the column flex-flow.  The result didn't seem desirable since if would scroll horizontally as columns, not vertically.

---

#### Modified Provided snippet

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71px;
  right: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* other stuff */
  transition: right 0.3s;
}

/* menuHide is removed via JavaScript when corresponding text is clicked */
.menu.menuHide {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 124px;
  width: 275px;
  top: 71px;
  right: -275px;
  transition: right 0.4s;
}

#faqMenu.menuHide {
  right: -400px;
}

#faqMenu.menu {
  top: 195px;
  height: auto;
  width: 400px;
  /*display: flex;*/
  /*bottom:0;*/ 
  overflow-y:scroll;
  flex-flow:unset;
  display:block;
  /* other stuff */
}

@media screen and (max-height: 900px) 
{
    div#faqMenu.menu {
        bottom:0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBar">
  <!-- left and center divs -->
  <div id="menuRight" class="menuBox">
    <!-- other things -->
    <div id="faqMenu" class="menu menuHide" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
      <!-- FAQs here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```